# Best practices to ensure Core Data can persist throughout development cycle

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I'm working on a Core Data iOS application. I've experienced a few cases where the database has become out of sync with the model, mostly due to my error (editing the active `xcdatamodel` by accident instead of creating a new version). This has resulted in loss of data for beta-testers who update to the bad version and experience app crashes. Currently the only way I know how to recover from these crashes is to delete and re-install the app.

What are some best practices to ensure my beta-tester's data will never be lost again? Currently I am doing the following:

> - Versioning my XCDatamodel (Editor->Add Model Version)
> - Enabled automigration:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                             [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
```

What other tips have been accrued by more experienced core data developers? Is there a good way to recover from core data model out-of-sync cases?

Comment: I think you've already identified the core problem (changing model version that has already been released into the wild). I try to add a model version every time the app is released, to prevent editing an active version.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new model version any time you change the model **is** the way you avoid this kind of problem. I don't know of any way to get Xcode or other tools to enforce that on you. You need to make sure that you don't commit changes to an existing data model version. Keep a close eye on what files are changed before committing to git (or whatever you use).

The other thing you need to do is make sure to test a new build using the same kind of upgrade that your beta users will be making. You're going along making changes and everything's OK, but before pushing that new build, start with data similar to what your beta testers will use and upgrade from that to the new version. If there's any issue of models not matching, you'll run into it, and you can fix it before sending the new build. The simplest way to do this is usually to:

1. Remove the app from your device
2. Install the most recent beta build and create some data
3. Install your new version and make sure the upgrade works as expected.

Testing the upgrade process is critical with any new build of an app, whether beta or release, so that you can find upgrade problems before your users do.